# How to test findById method?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jpa, junit, mockito

First - I've checked all previous topics around this question and none of them helped.

Having the following code:

```
    @DisplayName("GET RecipeUltraLight by id is successful")
    @Test
    public void givenRecipeId_whenGetRecipeDetailsById_thenReturnRecipeObject(){
        // given
        given(this.recipeRepository.findById(recipe.getId())).willReturn(Optional.of(recipe));
        given(this.recipeService.getRecipeById(recipe.getId())).willReturn(recipe);
        given(this.recipeConverter.toUltraLight(recipe)).willReturn(recipeUltraLightDto);

        // when
        RecipeUltraLightDto retrievedRecipe = recipeService.getRecipeUltraLightById(recipe.getId());

        // then
        verify(recipeRepository, times(1)).findById(recipe.getId());
        verify(recipeService, times(1)).getRecipeById(recipe.getId());
        verify(recipeConverter, times(1)).toUltraLight(recipe);

        assertThat(retrievedRecipe).isNotNull();
    }
```

gives me this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Recipe cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

Service method:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public RecipeUltraLightDto getRecipeUltraLightById(Long id) {
        Recipe recipe = getRecipeById(id);
        RecipeUltraLightDto dto = new RecipeUltraLightDto();

        dto = recipeConverter.toUltraLight(recipe);

        return dto;
    }

    // internal use only
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Recipe getRecipeById(Long id) {
        if (id == null || id < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        return recipeRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RecipeNotFoundException(
                        String.format("Recipe with id %d not found.", id)
                ));
    }
```

Setup:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RecipeService.class})
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
class RecipeServiceTest {
    @MockBean
    private RecipeConverter recipeConverter;

    @MockBean
    private RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RecipeService recipeService;

    private Recipe recipe;
    private RecipeUltraLightDto recipeUltraLightDto;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
        recipe = Recipe.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .name("Recipe")
                .description("Description")
                .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .difficulty(RecipeDifficulty.EASY)
                .minutesRequired(60)
                .portions(4)
                .authorId(1L)
                .views(0)
                .isVerified(false)
                .build();


        recipeUltraLightDto = RecipeUltraLightDto.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .name("Recipe")
                .build();
    }
```

I've tried:

1. Optinal.ofNullable()
2. Adding .isPresent()
3. Getting rid of .orElseThrow and going through if statements and using .get()
4. Kotlin

Will be glad if someone can help.

Comment: The error looks pretty clear `findById() should return Optional` also why are you registering behavior ont he service? You are testing it so why is that a mock?!

Comment: I'm mocking the repository layer.

Comment: Not according to `given(this.recipeService.getRecipeById(recipe.getId())).willReturn(recipe);` which indicates you are mocking the service as well.

Comment: The goal is to test the conversion method. That's why I'm mocking the service method it's invoking.

Comment: Why? That makes your mocking of the repository useless. Also it isn't mocking as the service is actually autowired. Remove that line and re-run your test now it will probably succeed.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum, that helped. So if one Service method depends on another I shouldn't mock any of them? If you want submit it as an anawer so I can select it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a mock of the object you are testing and with that basically also render the mocking of the repository useless.

You should remove the line `given(this.recipeService.getRecipeById(recipe.getId())).willReturn(recipe);` that way it will just call the method and call the repository. Which now will return the mocked result. As that is the behavior that will now kick in.

Answer (score -1):

It is clearly mentioned that the method `findById()` returning `Optional`, you need to get `Recipe` by invoking `Optional.get()`.

Comment: If I add to the test - given(this.recipeRepository.findById(recipe.getId()).get()).willReturn(recipe); it returns 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present.

Comment: I strongly suggest to read the error again!. The method **must** return an `Optional`  but it doesn't, hence the error.

Comment: Why because it is plain wrong.